# Particles higher than geometry

Tags: particles, geometry

i am having this issue, some particles are getting buried in the geometry and you can see only the tip of the object, is there a way to cast the particles a little bit higher than the geometry volume?[image]

Comment: Please show your particle with origin in edit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Simple way ... the Origin**

The placement of the particle uses the origin of the particle.  In edit mode move the mesh vertices away from the origin.  You can easily experiment which axis works best for your situation.

X or Y or Z

The origin of the mesh need not lie anywhere near the center of mass of the mesh.

For example a sphere particle may have its origin twice the distance of the diameter ... or in the geometric center.   A tree form particle probably would have its origin at the base of the trunk ... not in the geometric center.

Comment: I just realized that, i was trying things and then changed the origin of the object and worked. thx for the information :)